# Detect spikes with time-series data in Influxdb

Tags: time-series, influxdb

Assuming we have many services (imagine we're a service hosting company), every service runs multiple instances (containers), each instance periodically sends CPU usage to an Influxdb, the measurement is something like this:

| time | service | instance | cpu_usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100000 | S1 | I1 | 0.5 |
| 100000 | S1 | I2 | 0.6 |
| 100000 | S2 | I3 | 0.1 |
| 100001 | S1 | I1 | 0.2 |
| 100002 | S1 | I2 | 0.3 |
| 100002 | S2 | I3 | 0.8 |

We need to detect if the total CPU usage by a service surged in the past 5 minutes and should trigger an alert. The surge is defined as 1. the total CPU usage is greater than a predefined threshold, and 2. the CPU usage spikes by 30% in the past 5 minutes.

We can possibly have millions services, and each instance sends data back to Influxdb every 10 seconds, so there can be quite some data, but we don't need to keep the data for very long since we need to detect spikes only in the past 5 minutes.

Does Influxdb have the capability to detect such spikes, and even better to trigger alerts for it? If this is not something Influxdb is good at, what other alternative solutions you'd recommend? Thanks much.